# PHPCS Update doesn't show up

Tags: php, composer-php, phpcs

I'm at a loss, I hope someone can explain what I'm doing wrong:

I'm working on macOS (10.15.7). I tried to update PHPCS via Composer:

```
composer global require "squizlabs/php_codesniffer=*"
```

When I test the result it says:

```
% composer global show
Changed current directory to /Users/dave/.composer
[…]
squizlabs/php_codesniffer                      3.9.0  PHP_CodeSniffer token...
[…]
```

But when I try:

```
phpcs --version
```

it says:

```
PHP_CodeSniffer version 3.6.0 (stable) by Squiz (http://www.squiz.net)
```

What could be the reason?

Many thanks in advance for your hints!

Best regards
Dave

Comment: Are you sure this problem is in any way related to Composer itself?

Comment: @NicoHaase, no, probably not. Did my question give the impression that it is related mainly to Composer?

Comment: Yes, you've tagged the question with [tag:composer-php]

Answer (score 0):

Found the culprit: There was an old installation in `/Users/dave/bin`.